A wife is resurrected by her witch friend
It's about a woman and a man that are married but the woman's best mate is a female witch. The woman that's married dies and a year after the witch brings her back to life. The witch is normally a tarot card\crystal ball reader. The man moves on with this other lass, but the woman is determined to get him back. The woman also comes down flights of stairs in an amazing red dress and I think it was the husband that killed her.
Please help me find out what this movie is called, it's doing my head in lol. It's a 90's or 80's film I think and it's an American comedy; I think the married lass was called Lucy in the film.

I think I know what you're after, but do you remember anything else? Possible actors or what they looked like? Other scenes? Was it American?

the witch is narmaly a tarot card cystal ball reader... oh the woman also comes down flights of stairs in an amazing red dress and i think it was the husband that killed the woman lucy.. yes it was american.. dont know any actors i only remember it from my childhood

I think you might be thinking of "Hello Again" with Shelly Long.  
A suburban housewife chokes to death, and is brought back to life by her sister.  Shelly's character's name is Lucy.  And she has to fall in love again before the next full moon or she will die again.
Her husband is played by Corben Bernson and he falls in love with Sela Ward.  Lucy trys to get her husband back, but ends up falling in love with her doctor.

yes thats the one thank you soooo much was really doing my head in lol
